# Highlighting the current line in TextMate 2

Tags: textmate, textmate2

In TM 1.x, there was a preferences setting to enable the highlighting of the current line. This option seems to have disappeared in TM2. I assume there is some setting in tm_properties that can be set, but I cannot figure it out. I've tried setting lineHighlight to be a color, but this does not work. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible in TM2 yet, but there is an open [ticket on github](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/issues/197) regarding this issue. The lead developer is assigned to it, however it doesn't seem to have that high priority.

Eventually you should be able to do like this:

```
        settings = {
            lineHighlight = '#FF483E';
        };
```

This is from the Monokai Theme.

Comment: github issues have been closed for the project, for more info about this see: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Issue-Tracker

Comment: Unfortunately there is no effect for any value I set for this setting. Could it be a bug or may be there is some other setting in the preferences enables highlighting a current line?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set the colour for the current line in the line number and folding column on the left side of the window. Add the following after the first `{` in the beginning of the theme:

```
gutterSettings = {
        foreground = '#BBBBBB';
        background = '#333333';
        divider = '#BBBBBB';
        selectionBackground = '#FF8800';
        selectionForeground = '#000000';
    };
```